# Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'

Tags: flutter, dart

Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.

Tried to infer 'dynamic' for 'T' which doesn't work:

> Parameter 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T?)?'
> but argument is 'void Function(Object?)'.

The type 'dynamic' was inferred from:

> Parameter 'value' declared as     'T?'
> but argument is 'String'.
> Parameter 'items' declared as     'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'
> but argument is 'List<DropdownMenuItem>'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

I have DropDownformfield which shows above problem The code is

```
SizedBox(
                    width: deviceWidth * .9,
                    height: deviceHeight * 0.15,
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: _dropDownValue,
                      dropdownColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      iconSize: deviceWidth * .05,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'Constantia',
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            width: 2,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _dropDownValue = value.toString();
                          print(_dropDownValue);
                        });
                      },
                      items: <DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>[
                        menuItem('none'),
                        menuItem('10'),
                        menuItem('20'),
                        menuItem('30'),
                        menuItem('40'),
                        menuItem('50'),
                        menuItem('60'),
                        menuItem('70'),
                        menuItem('80'),
                        menuItem('90'),
                        menuItem('100'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

And widget as

```
DropdownMenuItem menuItem(String val) {
    final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: val,
      child: Container(
        width: deviceWidth * 0.6,
        child: Text(
          val,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Constantia',
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The Code works fine but Android Studio displays this as a problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you know how to properly type your `DropdownMenuItem<String>` but then completely forget about it and even change the type in the rest of the code?

Answer (score 4):

It is just intellisense suggesting you to provide generic types in your code.

> Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

Since you are providing all String values to `menuItems`. It is better to provide the generic type when you call them.

```
items : <DropdownMenuitem<String>>[
...
...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess halfway through your code you forgot what your types are... add them back and it will work:

```
items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                        menuItem('none'),
                        menuItem('10'),
                        menuItem('20'),
                        menuItem('30'),
                        menuItem('40'),
                        menuItem('50'),
                        menuItem('60'),
                        menuItem('70'),
                        menuItem('80'),
                        menuItem('90'),
                        menuItem('100'),
                      ],
```

And...

```
DropdownMenuItem<String> menuItem(String val) {
    final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: val,
      child: Container(
        width: deviceWidth * 0.6,
        child: Text(
          val,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Constantia',
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to provide generic types to avoid any bug or error in code. since you have mentioned DropDownMenuItem in your `menuItem` function android studio is giving you a warning that you have provided dynamic here.

```
items: <DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>[      // ==> change dynamic to String to solve that warning
                        menuItem('none'),
                        menuItem('10'),
                        menuItem('20'),
                        menuItem('30'),
                        menuItem('40'),
                        menuItem('50'),
                        menuItem('60'),
                        menuItem('70'),
                        menuItem('80'),
                        menuItem('90'),
                        menuItem('100'),
                      ],
```